# Problems generating a full screen view of HTML elements

Tags: iframe, element

I have a main page. This page has an iframe. The iframe has a page loaded in it that has a table and an iframe.

1) I want to display the main page iframe (which I am able to do by detecting the pressing of the 'Enter' key which executes a function that grabs the main page's iframe element and generates a full screen view of it -- however the background color is black and I can't read text. I've tried every CSS solution to change the background color. I tried everything I could find on here regarding that problem. Please help me find a solution that will work on all browsers.

2) Aside from that, I want to generate a full screen view of the main page's iframe document's table and generate a full screen view of the main page's iframe document's iframe. I am unable to generate a full screen view of the main page's iframe document's table. I am unable to generate a full screen view of the main page's iframe document's iframe. Please let me know how this can be done. I can successfully store the main page's iframe document in a variable using the contentWindow lingo -- but then using the variable to access its contents using the get Element by id nomenclature does not work. Please help me find a way to generate a full screen view of the main page's iframe document elements.

Please help with the two issues above.

My main page iframe id is "hello". The main page's iframe's document's table id is "jukebox". The main page's iframe's document's iframe id is "albumcover".

Not that this is of any actual debugging use other than letting you know that all elements discussed have id's and the get Element by id code still did not work or was able to be displayed by the function displaying a full screen view of elements...except when using the get Element by id code with the function displaying a full screen view of elements together when trying to generate a full screen display of the main page's iframe...it just helps someone who may help with creating a meaningful example. It'll help others finding this web page follow the issue's solution and if they have a similar problem then that information may allow them to follow the solution better and solve their own problem.

Thanks guys!

Main page:

```html
  function toggleFullScreen(x, y) {
   
    var videoElement;
    var q;
 var w;
 
 if (x == 1)
  {
    if (y == 0)
    {
    q = document.getElementById("hello");
    w = q.contentWindow.document;           
    alert("videoElement = documenttable;");    
    }
    else if (y == 1)
    {
    alert("videoElement = documentalbumiframe;");
    }
    else if (y == 2)
    {
    alert("videoElement = queuetextarea;");
    }
    else if (y == 3)
    {
    alert("videoElement = songlisttextarea;");
    }
      }
 else
 {
   if (y == 0)
     {
    videoElement = document.getElementById("hello");
   }
  }
 

  
    if ( (x == 1) || ( (x == 0) && (y == 0) ) )
 {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
     }
 }
  }
```

```html
<iframe src="menu.html" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello" id = "hello" style ="overflow-x:scroll"></iframe>
```

iFrame's document page:

```html
<table id="jukebox" border = "0"> 

...
```

```html
<iframe id="albumcover" height=432 width=450 frameborder=0 name = "cake" style =""></></iframe>
```

Comment: If you can find a solution, hold it for ransom and I'll fork over $40 for a working fix for each issue (all three). I've spent way too much time on this and this is the last additional computational technology I'm adding to my site. I'm through with development.

Comment: I could use $120, please see my answer. It's a quick draft. Wrote everything from scratch, no dependencies on any plugins, pure JS, CSS, and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

## SO36580875

### [Problems generating a full screen view of HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36580875/2813224)

This demo uses the [Full Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API):

- The external script file `fullview.js` is responsible for toggle button state (full screen mode/normal view mode), and determining what state the viewport should be changing to.
- Blue Button: Full Screen Toggle for `index.html` targets `<body>`
- Yellow Button: Full Screen Toggle for `jukebox.html` targets the `iframe#jBox`
- Fuschia Button: Full Screen Toggle for `cover.html` targets the `iframe#cBox`

In order to test the full screen feature, you must test it out of the IDE ([please see illustration](https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NTg4NjQxXzI5NjMwMTI). )

### [README.md](https://plnkr.co/edit/zeXV7tU8wJkUCxdTDVz4?p=info)

### [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/zeXV7tU8wJkUCxdTDVz4?p=preview)

### fullView.js

```
// fullView.js

function fullView(event) {

  var btn = this;
  var ele = this.id;
  var tgt = document.querySelector('.tgt' + ele);
  var state = btn.classList;

  if (state == 'off') {
    enterFS(tgt);
    btn.classList.remove('off');
    btn.classList.add('on');
  } else {
    exitFS();
    btn.classList.remove('on');
    btn.classList.add('off');
  }
}

function enterFS(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function exitFS() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}

// Usage

/*
Requirements: 
  A trigger element
    ex. <button>, <a>, etc.
  A target element
    ex. <body>, <section>, <div>, etc.
 
  Assign an id to the trigger.
    ex. <button id='btn1'></button>
    
  Assign a specific class to the target.      
  There is a naming pattern:
    '.tgt'+{{id of trigger}}
    ex. .tgtbtn1
      <body class='tgtbtn1'>
  
  Add an eventListener() to trigger.
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
  
  Use fullView as the eventHandler
    btn1.addEventListener('click', fullView, false);
*/
```

Comment: It's super late right now and I'm not grasping how to get the full screen functionality to work. Are you trying to make a jukebox component for me to use? Please explain how you are channeling through an iframe and accessing its components -- not to mention displaying the aforementioned components in full screen mode. I am too sleepy to dive into the code. If you post a brief guide -- that would help.  As of now, when I click anything on the index.html main page, there is no switch to full screen mode.

Comment: >Are you trying to make a jukebox component for me to use?< No it's a mockup, I assume you already have one or have plans for one in the future.>As of now, when I click anything on the index.html main page, there is no switch to full screen mode< The last sentence explains that the demo cannot function within the Plunker IDE (integrated development environment) is inhibiting full screen. It functions when outside of IDE. The image I provided shows you which button to push for Full Page mode.

Comment: <The last sentence explains that the demo cannot function within the Plunker IDE (integrated development environment) is inhibiting full screen. It functions when outside of IDE. The image I provided shows you which button to push for Full Page mode> lol...gotcha...I was operating on zero sleep after two days of work...I missed that b/c I had to skim to be able to process anything...let me look @ it again. I guessed that it wasn't a jukebox solution...I just didn't have the energy to comprehend the jukebox-ish entity you made. brb!

Comment: It looks likes you are just displaying jukebox.html full screen instead of just the table element 'jukebox' within jukebox.html. Please clarify what exactly you are displaying full screen or what you intended for the fullView function to display full screen. I need to have a parent page display an iframe's document's table...in this plunker package, to demonstrate the functionality I desire, the table 'jukebox' would be displayed full screen. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, when I said I would pay $40, I meant $40 for *each* fix, meaning all three. $40 for each individual fix being delivered eventually or at once. Not $40 per fix. I'm sorry if you misinterpreted what I said. I have committed to paying someone else the $40 if the person can work out all issues. I would have paid you $40 for your help if you had solved the issues, but I think you did not grasp what functionality I was asking for -- you could have been in a rush or low on sleep -- no assumptions made. I appreciate your help and understand if you no longer want to work on this.

Comment: Your attempt was appreciated but I have to be fair to the person who is working on helping me out and make my offer exclusive to someone who understands what I was offering. My issues are not resolved yet by this person. I appreciate this community's help. Provided how someone was mislead by my payment offer I have to retract it on here in order to not have people work under false pretenses. Lesson learned.

Comment: Doesn't matter about the money, I've done far greater things on this forum for price of a "thank you". Besides, I was almost finished when you posted that offer. >I need to have a parent page display an iframe's document's table...in this plunker package, to demonstrate the functionality I desire, the table 'jukebox' would be displayed full screen.< I had fullView target the iframes. So if it's an element inside the iframe, then you'd have to use `windowContent` or most likely `documentContent`. Or you could call the script from index.html on jukebox.html using `parent`...

Comment: Just re-read your second paragraph...I was about to follow through with *the functionality I couldn't grasp* but I too must rescind my offer of going any further. Good day to you, sir.